# How to develop UI Screen based on carousel for Android Tablet

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, tablet

I have screen in which there are two containers placed vertically one after other,First One contains information of component which is displayed by carousel view placed in second container.

How can these be achieved,what are UI Components to be used ,For Carousel View any demo codes will be useful.For first component,Should i be using fragements or UI Component.

It would be better if i have good idea of UI Widgets that should be used

Answer (score 0):

If you want a carousel like feeling, you can make the one view an [ViewAdapter](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) and the other a fragment. Behind the scene you sync the data with callbacks or [e.g. Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/). 
The nice feature with the ViewAdapter, you can swipe the e.g. pictures and the fragment on the other side refresh with the right text.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this to create [carousel](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-D-Carousel)

## The Preparations

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="Carousel">
        <attr name="android:gravity" /> 
        <attr name="android:animationDuration" />
        <attr name="UseReflection" format="boolean"/>
        <attr name="Items" format="integer"/>
        <attr name="SelectedItem" format="integer"/>
        <attr name="maxTheta" format="float"/>
        <attr name="minQuantity" format="integer"/>
        <attr name="maxQuantity" format="integer"/>
    </declare-styleable>    
</resources>
```

## The Carousel Item Class

```
public class CarouselImageView extends ImageView 
    implements Comparable<carouselimageview> {

    private int index;
    private float currentAngle;
    private float x;
    private float y;
    private float z;
    private boolean drawn;

    public CarouselImageView(Context context) {
        this(context, null, 0);
    }   

    public CarouselImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CarouselImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public int compareTo(CarouselImageView another) {
        return (int)(another.z – this.z);
    }

    …
}
</carouselimageview>
```

## The Rotator Class

```
public class Rotator {
    private int mMode;
    private float mStartAngle;
    private float mCurrAngle;

    private long mStartTime;
    private long mDuration;

    private float mDeltaAngle;

    private boolean mFinished;

    private float mCoeffVelocity = 0.05f;
    private float mVelocity;

    private static final int DEFAULT_DURATION = 250;
    private static final int SCROLL_MODE = 0;
    private static final int FLING_MODE = 1;

    private final float mDeceleration = 240.0f;


    /**
     * Create a Scroller with the specified interpolator. If the interpolator is
     * null, the default (viscous) interpolator will be used.
     */
    public Rotator(Context context) {
        mFinished = true;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * Returns whether the scroller has finished scrolling.
     * 
     * @return True if the scroller has finished scrolling, false otherwise.
     */
    public final boolean isFinished() {
        return mFinished;
    }

    /**
     * Force the finished field to a particular value.
     *  
     * @param finished The new finished value.
     */
    public final void forceFinished(boolean finished) {
        mFinished = finished;
    }

    /**
     * Returns how long the scroll event will take, in milliseconds.
     * 
     * @return The duration of the scroll in milliseconds.
     */
    public final long getDuration() {
        return mDuration;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the current X offset in the scroll. 
     * 
     * @return The new X offset as an absolute distance from the origin.
     */
    public final float getCurrAngle() {
        return mCurrAngle;
    }   

    /**
     * @hide
     * Returns the current velocity.
     *
     * @return The original velocity less the deceleration. Result may be
     * negative.
     */
    public float getCurrVelocity() {
        return mCoeffVelocity * mVelocity - mDeceleration * timePassed() /* / 2000.0f*/;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the start X offset in the scroll. 
     * 
     * @return The start X offset as an absolute distance from the origin.
     */
    public final float getStartAngle() {
        return mStartAngle;
    }           

    /**
     * Returns the time elapsed since the beginning of the scrolling.
     *
     * @return The elapsed time in milliseconds.
     */
    public int timePassed() {
        return (int)(AnimationUtils.currentAnimationTimeMillis() - mStartTime);
    }

    /**
     * Extend the scroll animation. This allows a running animation to scroll
     * further and longer, when used with {@link #setFinalX(int)} 
     * or {@link #setFinalY(int)}.
     *
     * @param extend Additional time to scroll in milliseconds.
     * @see #setFinalX(int)
     * @see #setFinalY(int)
     */
    public void extendDuration(int extend) {
        int passed = timePassed();
        mDuration = passed + extend;
        mFinished = false;
    }

    /**
     * Stops the animation. Contrary to {@link #forceFinished(boolean)},
     * aborting the animating cause the scroller to move to the final x and y
     * position
     *
     * @see #forceFinished(boolean)
     */
    public void abortAnimation() {
        mFinished = true;
    }        

    /**
     * Call this when you want to know the new location.  If it returns true,
     * the animation is not yet finished.  loc will be altered to provide the
     * new location.
     */ 
    public boolean computeAngleOffset()
    {
        if (mFinished) {
            return false;
        }

        long systemClock = AnimationUtils.currentAnimationTimeMillis();
        long timePassed = systemClock - mStartTime;

        if (timePassed < mDuration) {
            switch (mMode) {
                case SCROLL_MODE:

                    float sc = (float)timePassed / mDuration;
                        mCurrAngle = mStartAngle + Math.round(mDeltaAngle * sc);    
                    break;

                 case FLING_MODE:

                    float timePassedSeconds = timePassed / 1000.0f;
                    float distance;

                    if(mVelocity < 0)
                    {
                        distance = mCoeffVelocity * mVelocity * timePassedSeconds - 
                        (mDeceleration * timePassedSeconds * timePassedSeconds / 2.0f);
                    }
                    else{
                        distance = -mCoeffVelocity * mVelocity * timePassedSeconds - 
                        (mDeceleration * timePassedSeconds * timePassedSeconds / 2.0f);
                    }

                    mCurrAngle = mStartAngle - Math.signum(mVelocity)*Math.round(distance);

                    break;                    
            }
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            mFinished = true;
            return false;
        }
    }    

    /**
     * Start scrolling by providing a starting point and the distance to travel.
     * 
     * @param startX Starting horizontal scroll offset in pixels. Positive
     *        numbers will scroll the content to the left.
     * @param startY Starting vertical scroll offset in pixels. Positive numbers
     *        will scroll the content up.
     * @param dx Horizontal distance to travel. Positive numbers will scroll the
     *        content to the left.
     * @param dy Vertical distance to travel. Positive numbers will scroll the
     *        content up.
     * @param duration Duration of the scroll in milliseconds.
     */
    public void startRotate(float startAngle, float dAngle, int duration) {
        mMode = SCROLL_MODE;
        mFinished = false;
        mDuration = duration;
        mStartTime = AnimationUtils.currentAnimationTimeMillis();
        mStartAngle = startAngle;
        mDeltaAngle = dAngle;
    }    

    /**
     * Start scrolling by providing a starting point and the distance to travel.
     * The scroll will use the default value of 250 milliseconds for the
     * duration.
     * 
     * @param startX Starting horizontal scroll offset in pixels. Positive
     *        numbers will scroll the content to the left.
     * @param startY Starting vertical scroll offset in pixels. Positive numbers
     *        will scroll the content up.
     * @param dx Horizontal distance to travel. Positive numbers will scroll the
     *        content to the left.
     * @param dy Vertical distance to travel. Positive numbers will scroll the
     *        content up.
     */
    public void startRotate(float startAngle, float dAngle) {
        startRotate(startAngle, dAngle, DEFAULT_DURATION);
    }

    /**
     * Start scrolling based on a fling gesture. The distance travelled will
     * depend on the initial velocity of the fling.
     * 
     * @param velocityAngle Initial velocity of the fling (X) 
     * measured in pixels per second.
     */
    public void fling(float velocityAngle) {

        mMode = FLING_MODE;
        mFinished = false;

        float velocity = velocityAngle;

        mVelocity = velocity;
        mDuration = (int)(1000.0f * Math.sqrt(2.0f * mCoeffVelocity * 
                Math.abs(velocity)/mDeceleration));

        mStartTime = AnimationUtils.currentAnimationTimeMillis();        
    }
}
```

## The Carousel Class

```
private class FlingRotateRunnable implements Runnable {

    /**
     * Tracks the decay of a fling rotation
     */     
    private Rotator mRotator;

    /**
     * Angle value reported by mRotator on the previous fling
     */
    private float mLastFlingAngle;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public FlingRotateRunnable(){
        mRotator = new Rotator(getContext());
    }

    private void startCommon() {
        // Remove any pending flings
        removeCallbacks(this);
    }

    public void startUsingVelocity(float initialVelocity) {
        if (initialVelocity == 0) return;

        startCommon();

        mLastFlingAngle = 0.0f;

        mRotator.fling(initialVelocity);

        post(this);
    }               

    public void startUsingDistance(float deltaAngle) {
        if (deltaAngle == 0) return;

        startCommon();

        mLastFlingAngle = 0;
        synchronized(this)
        {
            mRotator.startRotate(0.0f, -deltaAngle, mAnimationDuration);
        }
        post(this);
    }

    public void stop(boolean scrollIntoSlots) {
        removeCallbacks(this);
        endFling(scrollIntoSlots);
    }        

    private void endFling(boolean scrollIntoSlots) {
        /*
         * Force the scroller's status to finished (without setting its
         * position to the end)
         */
        synchronized(this){
            mRotator.forceFinished(true);
        }

        if (scrollIntoSlots) scrollIntoSlots();
    }

    public void run() {
        if (Carousel.this.getChildCount() == 0) {
            endFling(true);
            return;
        }           

        mShouldStopFling = false;

        final Rotator rotator;
        final float angle;
        boolean more;
        synchronized(this){
            rotator = mRotator;
            more = rotator.computeAngleOffset();
            angle = rotator.getCurrAngle();             
        }            

        // Flip sign to convert finger direction to list items direction
        // (e.g. finger moving down means list is moving towards the top)
        float delta = mLastFlingAngle - angle;                        

        //////// Should be reworked
        trackMotionScroll(delta);

        if (more && !mShouldStopFling) {
            mLastFlingAngle = angle;
            post(this);
        } else {
            mLastFlingAngle = 0.0f;
            endFling(true);
        }              
}
```

}

## layout

```
/**
 * Setting up images
 */
void layout(int delta, boolean animate){

    if (mDataChanged) {
        handleDataChanged();
    }

    // Handle an empty gallery by removing all views.
    if (this.getCount() == 0) {
        resetList();
        return;
    }

    // Update to the new selected position.
    if (mNextSelectedPosition >= 0) {
        setSelectedPositionInt(mNextSelectedPosition);
    }        

    // All views go in recycler while we are in layout
    recycleAllViews();        

    // Clear out old views
    detachAllViewsFromParent();


    int count = getAdapter().getCount();
    float angleUnit = 360.0f / count;

    float angleOffset = mSelectedPosition * angleUnit;
    for(int i = 0; i< getAdapter().getCount(); i++){
        float angle = angleUnit * i - angleOffset;
        if(angle < 0.0f)
            angle = 360.0f + angle;
        makeAndAddView(i, angle);           
    }

    // Flush any cached views that did not get reused above
    mRecycler.clear();

    invalidate();

    setNextSelectedPositionInt(mSelectedPosition);

    checkSelectionChanged();

    ////////mDataChanged = false;
    mNeedSync = false;

    updateSelectedItemMetadata();
    }
```

## make and add view

```
private void makeAndAddView(int position, float angleOffset) {
    CarouselImageView child;

    if (!mDataChanged) {
        child = (CarouselImageView)mRecycler.get(position);
        if (child != null) {

            // Position the view
            setUpChild(child, child.getIndex(), angleOffset);
        }
        else
        {
            // Nothing found in the recycler -- ask the adapter for a view
            child = (CarouselImageView)mAdapter.getView(position, null, this);

            // Position the view
            setUpChild(child, child.getIndex(), angleOffset);               
        }
        return;
    }

    // Nothing found in the recycler -- ask the adapter for a view
    child = (CarouselImageView)mAdapter.getView(position, null, this);

    // Position the view
    setUpChild(child, child.getIndex(), angleOffset);
}      

private void setUpChild(CarouselImageView child, int index, float angleOffset) {

    // Ignore any layout parameters for child, use wrap content
    addViewInLayout(child, -1 /*index*/, generateDefaultLayoutParams());

    child.setSelected(index == this.mSelectedPosition);

    int h;
    int w;

    if(mInLayout)
    {
        h = (this.getMeasuredHeight() - 
    this.getPaddingBottom() - this.getPaddingTop())/3;
        w = this.getMeasuredWidth() - 
    this.getPaddingLeft() - this.getPaddingRight(); 
    }
    else
    {
        h = this.getHeight()/3;
        w = this.getWidth();            
    }

    child.setCurrentAngle(angleOffset);
    Calculate3DPosition(child, w, angleOffset);

    // Measure child
    child.measure(w, h);

    int childLeft;

    // Position vertically based on gravity setting
    int childTop = calculateTop(child, true);

    childLeft = 0;

    child.layout(childLeft, childTop, w, h);
}
```

## track motion scroll

```
void trackMotionScroll(float deltaAngle) {

    if (getChildCount() == 0) {
        return;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < getAdapter().getCount(); i++){
        CarouselImageView child = (CarouselImageView)getAdapter().getView(i, null, null);
        float angle = child.getCurrentAngle();
        angle += deltaAngle;
        while(angle > 360.0f)
            angle -= 360.0f;
        while(angle < 0.0f)
            angle += 360.0f;
        child.setCurrentAngle(angle);
        Calculate3DPosition(child, getWidth(), angle);          
    }

    // Clear unused views
    mRecycler.clear();        

    invalidate();
}
```

## scroll into slot

```
/**
 * Brings an item with nearest to 0 degrees angle to this angle and sets it selected 
 */
private void scrollIntoSlots(){

    // Nothing to do
    if (getChildCount() == 0 || mSelectedChild == null) return;

    // get nearest item to the 0 degrees angle
    // Sort itmes and get nearest angle
    float angle; 
    int position;

    ArrayList<carouselimageview> arr = new ArrayList<carouselimageview>();

    for(int i = 0; i < getAdapter().getCount(); i++)
        arr.add(((CarouselImageView)getAdapter().getView(i, null, null)));

    Collections.sort(arr, new Comparator<carouselimageview>(){
        @Override
        public int compare(CarouselImageView c1, CarouselImageView c2) {
            int a1 = (int)c1.getCurrentAngle();
            if(a1 > 180)
                a1 = 360 - a1;
            int a2 = (int)c2.getCurrentAngle();
            if(a2 > 180)
                a2 = 360 - a2;
            return (a1 - a2) ;
        }           
    });        

    angle = arr.get(0).getCurrentAngle();

    // Make it minimum to rotate
    if(angle > 180.0f)
        angle = -(360.0f - angle);

    // Start rotation if needed
    if(angle != 0.0f)
    {
        mFlingRunnable.startUsingDistance(-angle);
    }
    else
    {
        // Set selected position
        position = arr.get(0).getIndex();
        setSelectedPositionInt(position);
        onFinishedMovement();
    }        
}
```

## scroll to child

```
void scrollToChild(int i){      

    CarouselImageView view = (CarouselImageView)getAdapter().getView(i, null, null);
    float angle = view.getCurrentAngle();

    if(angle == 0)
        return;

    if(angle > 180.0f)
        angle = 360.0f - angle;
    else
        angle = -angle;

        mFlingRunnable.startUsingDistance(-angle);
}
```

## Here’s the Calculate3DPosition method:

```
private void Calculate3DPosition
(CarouselImageView child, int diameter, float angleOffset){
    angleOffset = angleOffset * (float)(Math.PI/180.0f);

    float x = -(float)(diameter/2*Math.sin(angleOffset));
    float z = diameter/2 * (1.0f - (float)Math.cos(angleOffset));
    float y = - getHeight()/2 + (float) (z * Math.sin(mTheta));

    child.setX(x);
    child.setZ(z);
    child.setY(y);
}
```

## getChildStaticTransformation

```
protected boolean getChildStaticTransformation
    (View child, Transformation transformation) {

    transformation.clear();
    transformation.setTransformationType(Transformation.TYPE_MATRIX);

    // Center of the item
    float centerX = (float)child.getWidth()/2, centerY = (float)child.getHeight()/2;

    // Save camera
    mCamera.save();

    // Translate the item to it's coordinates
    final Matrix matrix = transformation.getMatrix();
    mCamera.translate(((CarouselImageView)child).getX(), 
                ((CarouselImageView)child).getY(), 
                ((CarouselImageView)child).getZ());

    // Align the item
    mCamera.getMatrix(matrix);
    matrix.preTranslate(-centerX, -centerY);
    matrix.postTranslate(centerX, centerY);

    // Restore camera
    mCamera.restore();      

    return true;
}
```

## getChildDrawingOrder

```
protected int getChildDrawingOrder(int childCount, int i) {

        // Sort Carousel items by z coordinate in reverse order
        ArrayList<carouselimageview> sl = new ArrayList<carouselimageview>();
        for(int j = 0; j < childCount; j++)
        {
            CarouselImageView view = (CarouselImageView)getAdapter().
                        getView(j,null, null);
            if(i == 0)
                view.setDrawn(false);
            sl.add((CarouselImageView)getAdapter().getView(j,null, null));
        }

        Collections.sort(sl);

        // Get first undrawn item in array and get result index
        int idx = 0;

        for(CarouselImageView civ : sl)
        {
            if(!civ.isDrawn())
            {
                civ.setDrawn(true);
                idx = civ.getIndex();
                break;
            }
        }

        return idx;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks ,Let me check and Update you.

Answer (score -2):

*Edited to avoid absurdity*

You should try using [HorizontalScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @IlijaDimov I totally agree with the idea, but when it is a link to some blog post. Here I provided a link to the API documentation that is not about to disappear

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Yazan Are you serious? There is a question mark but this is rhetoric, not a question.

Comment: @TahirYasin I will surely post this as a new question and enjoy answers